# How do I create a list of links for all pastes in a Django pastebin app?

Tags: python, django, pastebin

I have set up a pastebin app with Django but I would like to be able to create a list of links to each individual paste on my homepage's template. I have been trying out a number of different things but am struggling to figure it out.

Here is what I have so far on the template, the app is named oxybeles:

```
<ul>
{% for ????? in ????? %}               
<a href="{% url oxybeles_detail item.uuid %}">A Link</a>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And here is the relevant back-end code:

models.py

```
class PastedItem(models.Model):

    uuid = models.CharField(_('identifier'), max_length=36, unique=True)
    artist = models.CharField(_('artist'), max_length=50)
    album = models.CharField(_('album'), max_length=50)
    in_response_to = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='responses',
        blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('in response to'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="pasted_items",
        verbose_name=_('user'))
    pasted_at = models.DateTimeField(_('pasted at'), auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.uuid

    def save(self):
        if not self.uuid:
            self.uuid = str(uuid4())  # random so it can't be easily guessed
        super(PastedItem, self).save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('oxybeles_detail', (), { 'slug': self.uuid })
        get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

views.py

```
def new(request, form_class=PastedItemForm, template_name="oxybeles/new.html"):

    form = form_class()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST["action"] == "paste":
            form = form_class(request.user, request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                item = form.save(commit=False)
                item.user = request.user
                item.save()
                request.user.message_set.create(
                    message=ugettext("Your album has been saved."))
                    # some problem with ugettext_lazy here
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('oxybeles_detail',
                                            args=(item.uuid,)))
    return render_to_response(template_name,
                              {'form': form,},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
new = login_required(new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for item in items
```

where items is a queryset full of PastedItem's:

```
items = PastedItem.objects.all()
```

and items is proffered to the template:

```
{'form':form, 'items': items}
```